# Generate PDF using 'letter paper'

Tags: java, pdf, itext, letter

I've come across the expression "Letter paper" (or letter-paper) lately, but I have never heard it before and I am not sure what it is, I am beginning to think this is not a standard expression. Anyway I tried to find out something about it, but it looks like it is not very commonly used at least with this wording as far as Java PDF generation goes. A letter page should be some kind of a template I assume, but then I do not know why isn't it called that. It should be used for common logos in the corners for example or for common footers. I could not find any tutorial or explanation on what is actually is or how to apply it to my PDF generating procedure.

Can anyone please explain to me what it is, (why is it called this) and maybe how to apply it to my PDF generation? I am using iText.

Comment: It seems 'letter-paper' might just be a way of saying 'A4'.  Paper the size you might use for a standard letter.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not so, or at least not entirely, the customer mentioned that the "letter-paper" should contain a logo and some footer, and the actual (additional) data should printed on this template (I assume)... I'm not sure anymore : (

Comment: i have updated my answer , check it now

Comment: If  your customer talks about the paper size, cf. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_(paper_size)

Comment: The correct term is company stationery. Please take a look at this example from my book: http://1t3xt.be/?140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referred to normal [A4 size papers size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_%28paper_size%29) of 8.5" width x 11" height.

For PDF generation you can specify the size when creating the pdf object.

i have used the following with my iText pdf export

```
document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 16, 16, 64, 34);
```

if you want help to specific to particular pdf library, if you give the pdf library name i will try to find out

**Update: For your comment**

> the customer mentioned that the "letter-paper" should contain a logo
>   and some footer, and the actual (additional) data should printed on
>   this template (I assume).

may be customer needs to have header and footer in each page of generated PDF. In iText you can specify Header and Footer using java code and these will be inserted in all pages in resulting PDF.

you can get the samples for using header and footer here

https://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=86

https://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=87

Comment: Okay than, I was beginning to think that the letter-paper the customer mentioned is something totally different, you are the second person to associate it with paper size so I will accept this approach thanks a lot.

Comment: "Letter" size is NOT equal to A4 and A4 is NOT 8,5 by 11 inches.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to paper size, "Letter" refers to a format mostly used in the US as opposed to A4 which is commonly used in Europe.

A letter page is 8,5" by 11" which is slightly wider but slightly shorter than a standard A4 size (which is 8,3" by 11.7").

You can find all common page sizes here:
http://www.dpandi.com/paper/